# C++ input in the while statement

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int sum = 0, value = 0;
    while (std::cin >> value)
        sum += value;
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I give 1 2 3 q in terminal, then output is 6. But when i give 1 2 3 4.0, then output is 10.

Why does this program print 10 not 6?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: _"Why does this program print 10 not 6?"_ Because the sum of `1 2 3 4` is `10`??

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator >> for the type `int` reads digits until a non-digit is encountered.

So the condition

```
while (std::cin >> value)
```

evaluates to false when the dot is encountered in the buffer.

1 2 3 4 are valid numbers. The first non-valid symbol is '.'.

Answer (score 0):

You typed `1`, then `(space) 2`, then `(space) 3`, then `(space) 4`, then `.0`.

When you do `std::cin >> value`, it ignores any whitespace, then tries to read as many digits as possible, and fails if there are no digits. `4` is a valid integer so that is what is read. `.0` is not so the loop ends at that point.

1+2+3+4 is 10.